# Create sidebar in mac app with sections

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, core-data

I want to create a sidebar in one of my mac applications. Basically it will look much like the Things sidebar.

Here is the picture that I basically want to recreate:

[image: screenshot]

I can't figure out how to show the "sections" (collect, focus and active projects) and how to have certain items always show up (inbox, today, next, etc...) and finally I would really appreciate if someone would explain how to make the active projects section, with the triangle.

Also I need the active projects section to load from an entity in core data.

I would also really appreciate if you could post an example.

Answer (score 5):

Apple's "SourceView" sample should be helpful with this:

[Apple Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

[PXSourceList](http://github.com/perspx/PXSourceList) is an open source `NSOutlineView` subclass specifically built for mimicking what you posted.  I've used it in a number of projects, and it's very easy and flexible to use. I *highly* recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

The active projects section is probably just a 1 column [NSOutlineView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOutlineView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with no column header.